# How to have a text element say '<'

Tags: xml, svg

I am currently drawing SVGs and I want to have a text element that contains a less than symbol.  When I try:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text x="40" y="40" fill="Black" font-size="25" font-weight="bold" font-family="courier new" ><</text>
</svg>
```

I get the following error: "StartTag: invalid element name"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<` and `>` characters are special characters in HTML and SVG, used to denote tags, like `<svg>` and `<text>`. The renderer thinks you are trying to start a new tag when you use the `<` in your code. This is why you're getting the error `"StartTag: invalid element name"`

To tell the renderer you want to print the `<` character and not start a tag, you need to use an "escape code." In this case, the escape code you want is `&lt;`

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="40" y="40" fill="Black" font-size="25" font-weight="bold" font-family="courier new" >&lt;</text>
</svg>
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omqsd458/) demonstrating the use of that escape code.

There are [many other escape codes you can use](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/htmlchars.html), too. They can be useful if your keyboard lacks a certain special character, like the British pound, or if you want to output special characters without affecting how your HTML or SVG is parsed by the renderer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually refer to [this page](http://character-code.com/) and you can also use the hex equivalent, eg `<` translates to `&#x3C;`, which is [Unicode U+003C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c/index.htm).